# How disable changing variable inside array?

Tags: java

I have 2D array:

```
    int[] zero = {
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1};        

    int[][] tab = {zero, zero};
```

I want to change this:

```
tab[0][0] = 0;
```

But when I did that It also change tab[1][0]. Can you tell me how can I disable that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By making it so the two arrays are different objects rather than the same object.

One way to achieve that would be:

```
int[][] tab = {zero.clone(), zero.clone()};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)